# Why do the Vertrigo 2.21 (MySQL server do not start) do not work under Windows 7?

Tags: mysql, apache, windows-7

It says that port 3306 might be busy - i have changed it (Settings>Components Settings) but just nothing?

> VertrigoServ → MySQL database server
>   does not work correctly. Check whether
>   other applications use the important
>   port (3306) and terminate them.
>   Moreover, check firewall settings and
>   correctness the configuration files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the similar problem and I have tried it ... but it didn't work for me so I have found another solution ...

In **Config files** you will find **my.ini** ... open it and you will find "**port = 3306**" its on line 4th in my case ... change it to something like "**port = 3307**" that's what I did and restart.

If it still wont work then go to

"**Settings -> Program Settings**"

and click "**Return to default settings**" and click "**Save settings and restart server**"

after server restarts

again go to "**Settings -> Program Settings**"

and enable or tick "**Run server as service**" and "**Automatically start servers**" in miscellaneous tab on left top of the panel ...

and later always "***run as administrator***" ...

I forgot to mention that **I am using Windows 7** ...

Answer (score 2):

Try to run as administrator .... problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

I found another problem related to this. My installation directory was:

```
C:\dev\tools\VertrigoServ2_35\Mysql
```

and watching the event viewer of Windows I saw:

> Can't create test file C:\dev  ools\VertrigoServ2_35\Mysql\data\IURESTI.lower-test"

To solve the problem I replaced all `\\` with `\\\\` in:

```
basedir=C:\\\\dev\\\\tools\\\\VertrigoServ2_35\\\\Mysql\\\\

datadir=C:\\\\dev\\\\tools\\\\VertrigoServ2_35\\Mysql\\data\\\\
```

inside the file `my.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

Try in command prompt

```
telnet localhost 3306
```

what does it return back to you?

Comment: Could not connect to this host on port 3306: connection failed. [br]

If i try "telnet localhost 80" → thats all right